# creating a cpio archive ingnoring modification time of files

Tags: linux, embedded, cpio

how can I create a cpio archive by ignoring the modification times of the files (or imposing them at a known value)?

The context is as follows: in the build process of an embedded project some "intermediate" files are stored in a cpio archive. They will be used by the FW of a microcontroller, so neither uid/gid nor modification time is involved. My constraint is that I must be able to rebuild a certain version at any time, ensuring that I always get the exact same binary (bit by bit). But if the modification time is also stored in the cpio this constraint is no longer met.

Comment: There is a new `star` based answer in the related question.